# Java: Generate nCr array from input String array and returning it

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, math

I'm wanting to return a complete array of all possible combinations from an input array. I'd like to generate n pick k combinations where k=1 to n. I've been hugely unsuccessful so far.

```
static void combinationUtil(String[] arr, String data[], int start, int end, int index, int r, float[][] info) {
        // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
        strat newStrat = new strat(0, 0, 0, null);
        if (index == r) {
            //THIS IS WHERE THE COMBINATION I WANT APPEARS
            return;
        }

        for (int i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++) {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r, info);
        }
        return;
    }

public static void getCombinations(String[] arr, int n, int r, float[][] info) {
        String[] data = new String[r];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n - 1, 0, r, info);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //Array I want to get all k 1:n combinations of
        String[] array = { "TST1", "TST2", "TST3"} 
        //start a timer because that's always fun
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        //cycle through all 'pick k values'
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            getCombinations(array, n, i, info);
        }
        //Math's up. How Long did that take?
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        //IDEALLY PRINT THE COMBINATIONAL ARRAY HERE
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(_____));
        //Don't forget to print the time ;)
        System.out.println("Duration: "+(endTime - startTime)+" ns");
    }
```

I've tried everything I could think of and google. From passing the "data" array to the function, concatenating it with its prior self, copying the old array to a new one where the newest index is the newest 'data', ArrayLists, Stacks, .push(), .add(), getting the total number of possible combinations and inserting them in a global array index... Nothing... I'm burnt.. Of course ideally the result would look like:

```
[["TST1"], ["TST2"], ["TST3"], ["TST1", "TST2"], ["TST1", "TST3"], ["TST2", "TST3"], ["TST1", "TST2", "TST3"]
```

At this point maybe even add in a little

```
"It is done. Go. Be happy!"
```

The code above works all well and good, but the combination only appears in combinationUtil(), rather than where I want to use the cumulative result in main(). So, what am I doing miserably wrong?

Comment: Make `data` a static member variable of the class (that contains method `main`), as in: `private static String[] data`. That way you can access it from anywhere in the class, including inside method `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate possible combination of r element in array of size n. You can try this code. I called the function as nCr (not sure if that is the right mathematical notation for the problem we are trying to solve)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array2 = { "TST1", "TST2", "TST3"};
    List<List<String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (var i: Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3)) {
        l.addAll(nCr(array2, i));
    }
    System.out.println(l);
}

private static List<List<String>> nCr(String[] array, int r) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (r == 0) return result;
    if (r == 1) return nC1(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - r + 1; i++) {
        List<List<String>> result2 = nCr(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i + 1, array.length),
                r - 1);
        for (var x: result2 ) {
            x.add(array[i]);
            result.add(x);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static List<List<String>> nC1(String[] array) {
    List<List<String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (var x: array) {
        l.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(x)));
    }
    return l;
}
```

---

output:

```
[[TST1], [TST2], [TST3], [TST2, TST1], [TST3, TST1], [TST3, TST2], [TST3, TST2, TST1]]
```

Comment: Very nice. Even faster than what I was using too!

Comment: It is a recursive function. We already know the base case of 0 and 1 selection. For 2 selection, we choose 1 item and 1 selection lists from remaining items. And then we multiply chosen one item to the selection list from remaining items. Try to think how u will u chose 2 items from a list. I will add references. One math book explain this nicely and I can help. It is what they call combinatorics.